# CoreData: error: API Misuse: error when using SectionNameKeyPath in NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: swift, core-data, ios10

In iOS10, I am getting this error when I call performFetch() with an NSFetchedResultsController when I try to pass in a SectionNameKeyPath:

> CoreData: error:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
    let sectionName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "testClass", ascending: true)
let number = NSSortDescriptor(key: "ordinal", ascending: true)
let inventoryName = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: false)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sectionName, number, inventoryName]

if let srcName = sources.fetchedObjects?[0].srcName { //TODO: this is good for 1 source, multiple sources will require an external "source" variable.
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ == %K", srcName, "mySource.srcName")
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
}

let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "testClass", cacheName: "Root")
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
_options = aFetchedResultsController

do {
    try _options!.performFetch()
} catch {
    let nserror = error as NSError
    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
}
```

The fetch still runs, but I get a a bunch of the errors above and I believe it eventually causes a crash in the app a little later. If I pass in nil for SectionNameKeyPath, the error does not occur (but, of course, I need the sections in the result for a sectioned tableview).  "TestClass" is a String in coredata and a property of the entity I'm fetching.  Any idea what could be happening?